# Como transformar todos os valores de um data.frame em numericos?

Tags: r, data.frame

Importei uma base de dados no R e ao executar a função t() para transpor linhas e colunas, todos os valores que deveriam ser numéricos foram transformados em fator!

Como poderia transformar todos os valores de todas as colunas em numéricos? Eu consigo transformar coluna por coluna, porém nesse caso tenho 5570 colunas e todas precisam ser transformadas em numéricas..

Alguma solução simples? Dou preferencia para solução utilizando tidyverse.

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: *ao executar a função t()*: não faça isso a um data.frame.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Três coisas: primeiro, `t()` não é recomendado para um `data.frame`. Segundo, quando for importar, coloca o argumento `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` no `read.csv()`. Terceiro, tenta usar `as.numeric()` em tudo. Imagino que vá funcionar.